# Creating Multiple Records in Airtable using Form and Script

Tags: javascript, airtable

I'm trying to create a script in airtable that takes user input from a form and creates multiple records. The inputs are the number of payments, date of first payment, frequency (we can just assume monthly now), and the payment amount. Here is the code that I have so far. I'm getting an error that Property 'numberAsync' does not exist on type '{ config(): {}; }' for all of my inputs.

```
// Get the number of records to create from the form
let numRecords = input.numberAsync('Number of Payments');

// Get the due date from the form
let dueDate = input.dateAsync('Due Date');

// Get the payment amount from the form
let paymentAmount = input.numberAsync('Payment');

// Create a while loop to create the specified number of records
let i = 1;
while (i <= numRecords) {
  // Create a new record with the current value of i, dueDate, and paymentAmount
  createRecord(i, dueDate, paymentAmount);
  // Increment i
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering is due to **how** you're trying to retrieve `input`. The numberAsync, dateAsync, and other similar functions aren't supported for scripting in Airtable.

Where did you get your script? I can't find any reference to your mentioned functions in the Airtable documentation.

Instead, you should use the `input.config()` function as the `airtable` documentation suggests, to prompt for input when running a script. Here's how you can modify your script to achieve your goal:

```
let config = input.config({
  title: 'Create Multiple Records',
  description: 'Enter the details for creating multiple records:',
  items: [
    { type: 'number', name: 'numRecords', label: 'Number of Payments' },
    { type: 'date', name: 'dueDate', label: 'Due Date' },
    { type: 'number', name: 'paymentAmount', label: 'Payment Amount' }
  ]
});

let numRecords = config.numRecords;
let dueDate = config.dueDate;
let paymentAmount = config.paymentAmount;

let i = 1;
while (i <= numRecords) {
  createRecord(i, dueDate, paymentAmount);
  // Increment i
  i++;
}

// Function to create a new record
function createRecord(index, dueDate, amount) {
  // Your logic to create a new record in Airtable goes here
  // For example:
   table.createRecordAsync({
     'Due Date': dueDate,
     'Payment Amount': amount
   });
}
```

I have not tested the code. It should just reflect the idea. If you need functions that access these values somewhere else in your code, you can wrap this logic in a class and create getter functions.

However, if you absolutely need the functions you mentioned on the input, you can extend the prototype of the input. You should be able to find some stuff on the internet about this. **However, this is highly not recommended.**

Comment: Thanks! I took some time away and came back to this. I got my initial code from chat GPT. I defined my inputs but am having some trouble with the first couple of lines. I'm getting errors that no inputs were expected but received 1.